# vue js button disable and enable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

1. when page is landing default next button is disabled, we will selected one radio button
   next button is disabled.
2. condition based on work with disable and enable next button

   {% if cust_package == '6 Free Trades'  %}
   Subscribe for more Trades options will be enabled once you consume all 6 free trades

   {% comment %} {% elif cust_package == " "  %}
    {% endcomment %}
   {% elif cust_package == "" %}
   Subscribe for more Trades options will be enabled once you consume all 6 free trades

   ```
                            {% endif %}
                    <hr style="position: relative;top: -4px;border-color: lightgray;">
                    <p class="head-trades" style="top: -11px;"> Subscribe for more Trades:</p>
                {% if cust_package and package_value != 0%}
                    <p class="sixfreetrade">
                        <input style="position: relative;width: 4%;left: 1px;"
                               type="radio" id="business"
                               name="flag" value="15 Trades for $6.99" v-model="subscribe" disabled>
                        <span style="" class="Business_postadTrade">15 Trades for $6.99 </span>
                    </p>
                    <div v-if="subscribe == '15 Trades for $6.99'">   
                        {% if cust_package %}
                        {% if cust_package == '15 Trades for $6.99' %}
                            {% if  package_value == 0 and cust_package == '15 Trades for $6.99' %}

                                <p style = "color: #DB0038;">* You consumed {{consumed_ads}} Trades and left with {{package_value}} Trade  * Please upgrade higher subscription if you want more Trades to post</p>
                            {% elif  package_value != 0 and cust_package == '15 Trades for $6.99' %}
                                <p>* You consumed {{consumed_ads}} trades and left with {{package_value}} trades.</p>
                                {% comment %} <p>* Want more ads in this month, please upgrade higher package</p> {% endcomment %}
                            {% endif %}

                        {% else %}
                        <p>* You consumed 0 trades and left with 15 trades.</p>
                        {% comment %} <p>* Want more ads in this month, please upgrade higher package</p> {% endcomment %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <p class="sixfreetrade">
                        <input style="position: relative;width: 4%;left: 1px;"
                               type="radio" id="business"
                               name="flag" value="30 Trades for $12.99" v-model="subscribe" disabled>
                        <span style="" class="Business_postadTrade">30 Trades for $12.99 </span>
                    </p>
                    <div v-if="subscribe == '30 Trades for $12.99'">
                        {% if cust_package %}
                        {% if cust_package == '30 Trades for $12.99' %}
                            {% if  package_value == 0 and cust_package == '30 Trades for $12.99' %}

                            <p style="color: #DB0038;">* You consumed {{consumed_ads}} Trades and left with {{package_value}} Trade  * Please upgrade higher subscription if you want more Trades to post</p>
                            {% elif  package_value != 0 and cust_package == '30 Trades for $12.99' %}
                            <p>* You consumed {{consumed_ads}} trades and left with {{package_value}} trades.</p>
                            {% comment %} <p>* Want more ads in this month, please upgrade higher package</p> {% endcomment %}
                            {% endif %}

                        {% else %}
                        <p>* You consumed 0 trades and left with 30 trades.</p>
                        {% comment %} <p>* Want more ads in this month, please upgrade higher package</p> {% endcomment %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <p class="sixfreetrade">
                        <input style="position: relative;width: 4%;left: 1px;"
                               type="radio" id="business"
                               name="flag" value="120 Trades for $24.99" v-model="subscribe" disabled>
                        <span style="" class="Business_postadTrade">120 Trades for $24.99 </span>
                    </p>
                    <div v-if="subscribe == '120 Trades for $24.99'">
                        {% if cust_package %}
                        {% if cust_package == '120 Trades for $24.99' %}
                            {% if package_value == 0 and cust_package == '120 Trades for $24.99' %}

                                <p style="color: #DB0038;">* You consumed {{consumed_ads}} Trades and left with {{package_value}} Trade  * Please upgrade higher subscription if you want more Trades to post</p>
                            {% elif package_value != 0 and cust_package == '120 Trades for $24.99' %}
                                <p>* You consumed {{consumed_ads}} trades and left with {{package_value}} trades.</p>
                                {% comment %} <p>* Want more ads in this month, please upgrade higher package</p> {% endcomment %}
                            {% endif %}

                        {% else %}
                        <p>* You consumed 0 trades and left with 120 trades.</p>
                        {% comment %} <p>* Want more ads in this month, please upgrade higher package</p> {% endcomment %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
   ```

default next button is disable and click on radio button next button is enable

Comment: Please add more information to your question. you should also provide some more code so that the context can be understood.

Comment: Please share code to what you have achieved ?

Comment: i am updated code